# SQL Syntax wrong Select Where Like

Tags: mysql, select, syntax, where-clause, sql-like

My phpmyadmin gives me the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '17, COL 19, COL 21, COL 23
FROM `table 1`
WHERE (COL 7
LIKE '%13%' OR COL ' at line 1
```

When I try to call like this:

```
SELECT COL 17, COL 19, COL 21, COL 23 
FROM `table 1` 
WHERE (COL 7 
LIKE '%13%' OR COL 1 
LIKE '%13%' OR COL 2 
LIKE '%13%' OR COLE 3 
LIKE '%13%')
```

I tried several options but did not work I probably oversee something but cannot find it.

Comment: It's the column names, you need to delimit them since they have blanks. E.g "col 1" (ANSI SQL), or perhaps back-ticks if MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the column names, which appear to have spaces in them, in single backticks:

```
SELECT `COL 17`, `COL 19`, `COL 21`, `COL 23`
FROM `table 1` 
WHERE (`COL 7` LIKE '%13%' OR `COL 1` LIKE '%13%' OR `COL 2` LIKE '%13%'
    OR `COL 3` LIKE '%13%')
```